# show using probability axioms $P[A\backslash B] = PA - P[A\bigcap B]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show using probability axioms $P[A\backslash B] = PA - P[A\bigcap B]$

I started by rewriting the left hand side as $P[A\backslash B] = P[A\bigcap B^C] $

Then substitution and rearragement gives $P[A \bigcap B^C] + P[A \bigcap B] = PA$

What should I do next (if this is correct)?

Also, how do I show it without using the fact: $P[A\backslash B] = P[A\bigcap B^C] $ since its not formally one of the axioms?

Comment: $P(A\setminus B)=P(A\cap B^c)$ is a direct consequence of $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$. So no axiom is needed.

Comment: Why not use `\cap` when `\bigcap` is not needed (for example, everywhere in this post)?

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? OP clearly showed what they have done.

Comment: So, you know that $P[A\backslash B] = P[A\cap B^C] $ and that $P[A \cap B^C] + P[A \cap B] = P[A]$ and you are asking why $P[A\backslash B] = P[A]-P[A \cap B]$, right? Maybe using symbolds could help: you know that $$x=y\qquad y+z=t$$ and you want to show that $$x=t-z$$ Seems like very elementary algebra, no?

Answer (score 2):

I preassume that $A,B$ are measurable sets and that $P$ denotes a probability measure.

Then $P$ is $\sigma$-additive and $P(\varnothing)=0$.

Define $E_1=A\cap B^c$, $E_2=A\cap B$ and $E_n=\varnothing$ for $n\geq3$

Then these sets are measurable and mutually disjoint and the $\sigma$-additivity of $P$ tells us that: $$P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n)$$

Working this out and making use of $P(\varnothing)=0$ we arrive at:$$P(A)=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A\cap B)$$ or equivalently:$$P(A\setminus B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Can you explain the reason you set the left hand side equal to P(A) in the second equation?

Comment: I'm not sure why. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Because $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B)\cup\varnothing\cup\varnothing\cup\cdots=A$.

Comment: Of course this explains competently the related setting but I am ready to bet this is not what is stopping the OP. See my comment on main here and the other question by the OP, where the problem is to understand that $x+y-z\leqslant t$ with $z$ the probability of a set, implies $t\geqslant x+y-1$.